# Access to locally scoped variable via string – anything but eval?

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

Please consider this snippet:

```
let variableName = 'internalVariable';
{
  let internalVariable = 'whatever';
  console.log(eval(propertyKey)); // prints 'whatever'
}
```

What are my options to accessing `internalVariable` via the string stored in `variableName`? I was hoping for something like `scope[variableName]`, but there seems to be nothing like it.

Given this particular scenario, are there any alternatives to using `eval`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that *at all*?

Comment: You can always use an object and the `[ ]` to reference properties dynamically.

Comment: `let` does *not* create a property, so the whole idea is not possible.

Comment: This should be handled with an object `{internalProperty: "whatever"}` not a named variable.

Comment: @trincot you're right, better name it `internalVariable` then?

Comment: Yes, that would be an appropriate name

Comment: @Pointy the example obviously does not present the real world usage I had in mind. Let's just say I'm curious as to weather it's generally possible

Comment: @panepeter Well no, it's not possible.

Comment: No, it is not generally possible. Declared variables cannot be accessed via anything like the C++ `&` operator or via dynamic synthesis of a variable name, except via `eval()`. Using `eval()` is generally a bad idea as it prevents runtime optimization of your code.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, that's the answer I was looking for! I was sort of expecting that, but could not find any source stating it explicitly. Mind making your comment an answer?

Comment: "does not present the real world usage" ... then we can't present a real world solution.

Comment: @JonasW. I did not want a solution to my problem, but an answer to my question. But [thank you all for your help](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) anyway!

Comment: @panepeter The point is that you're presenting an X-Y problem with no context. There may be a good way to do what you want, but we don't know what you want. Chalk it up to people wanting to solve underlying problems, not just what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations where dynamic access to something *like* a variable is required, the idiomatic thing to do is employ an object and dynamically compute property names as appropriate.

```
var obj = {};

obj[getPropertyName()] = "hello world";
```

Variables declared in functions with `var`, `let`, or `const` do exist as properties of something like an object (the closure of a function call), but JavaScript does not provide any way of referring to that thing as an object. Using `eval()` is possible, but generally it's a bad idea because runtime optimization is not attempted in modern runtime systems because `eval()` makes that intractably complicated.

The only way a variable is aliased in JavaScript is via the `arguments` object, and that's sufficiently weird that it's explicitly discouraged in "strict" mode.

[edit] — in re: Bergi's comment below, the (generally deprecated) `with` statement allows implicit references to object properties, and the `export` mechanism for modules can create aliases, though to me it's hard to imagine that being a good thing in actual practice.

Comment: Also: `with` and ES6 module exports

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure you're right but I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean.

Comment: It was in reference to "*the only way a variable is aliased*", but of course neither of the three mentioned mechanisms helps to access locally scoped (or even `let`-declared, like in the question example) variables.

Comment: @Bergi I'd never thought about the ramifications of using `import` to bind the same exported value to more than one symbol; that seems like a bug vector.

Comment: Given that all the aliases are immutable references I don't see a problem. It's much better than the current practice of referring to shared module object properties.